# How to use a custom SMTP settings in my WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, smtp, phpmailer, mailgun, email

I need to use custom SMTP settings for my WordPress site to send email through my email servers such as Mailgun or SendGrid.

Comment: There are a few plugins that take care of it all. One such I use is "Post SMTP By Yehuda Hassine". No need to mess with code, and has a light and easy interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in your theme function.php or your own plugin.

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'custom_phpmailer_init' );
function custom_phpmailer_init( $phpmailer ) {

    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    $phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.mailgun.com';
    $phpmailer->Port = 465;
    $phpmailer->Username = 'user_name';
    $phpmailer->Password =  '********';
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $phpmailer->From       = 'FromName@example.com';
    $phpmailer->FromName   = 'FromName';

}
```

Comment: [The WordPress Codex documentation on this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init).